# Objective-C get list of all custom papers

Tags: objective-c, macos, printing, nsprintinfo

I'm working on a little framework and I need to get a list of all available **custom papers**

In the [Core Printing Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/) there's only a method called [PMPrinterGetPaperList](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/PMPrinterGetPaperList), but it doesn't return custom paper:

```
This function obtains a list of the papers that a given printer claims to support.
The paper list does not include any custom paper sizes that may be available
```

If I open a pdf-document and then open the print-dialog I can create and select custom papers.

As summary I want to get a/the list of custom papers which I can create with print-dialog and with Objective-C method [PMPaperCreateCustom](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/PMPaperCreateCustom)

It has to be in Objective-C.

Any ideas? Thanks

**Edit1:**

Here is a snippet based on the first answer:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < printerCount; i++)
    {
        CFStringRef currentPrinterName;
        currentPrinter = (PMPrinter) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(printerList, i);
        currentPrinterName = PMPrinterGetName(currentPrinter);

        if ([(NSString *) currentPrinterName caseInsensitiveCompare:printerName] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            error = PMSessionCreatePageFormatList([[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] PMPrintSession], currentPrinter, &pageFormatList);

            if (error != noErr)
            {
                // TODO
            }

            NSUInteger pageCount = CFArrayGetCount(pageFormatList);

            for (int n = 0; n < pageCount; n++)
            {
                currentPage = (PMPageFormat) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(pageFormatList, n);

                error = PMGetPageFormatPaper(currentPage, &currentPaper);

                if (error != noErr)
                {
                    // TODO
                }

                if (PMPaperIsCustom(currentPaper))
                {
                    NSLog(@"It's custom");
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        currentPrinter = NULL;
    }
```

But I only get the list of 'normal' papers and no custom ones.

On print dialog I created a custom paper (see screenshot) and this should be in the list.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot xcode]

Comment: It's hard to tell the context from your snippet. Are you querying the same context as is used for the dialog? How was the custom paper and page format created/added? Is it the same session as that?

Comment: The custom paper was created with the native MacOsX Dialog, not with Objective-C.
But the created paper is globally available. I can select it as default paper in native printer settings, or I can select it as paper on each native printer dialog (e.g. if I want to print a pdf with native Viewer).

Answer (score 1):

It might work to use `PMSessionCreatePageFormatList()` to get all of the page formats, enumerate them, and, for each, call `PMGetPageFormatPaper()` to get its paper. You can use `PMPaperIsCustom()` to find out if each is a custom paper.

Answer (score 1):

Since the custom papers list is apparently not (currently) accessible via Core Printing and Cocoa Printing …

One could use Objective-C to read the plist which stores a dictionary of the custom papers created by the user:

*~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.custompapers.plist*

Then, use subsequently use `PMPaperCreateCustom` as needed.